# Simple graphics API with transparency, polygons, reading image pixels?

Tags: javascript, python, graphics, canvas, svg

I need a simple graphics library that supports the following functionality:

1. Ability to draw polygons (not just rectangles!) with RGBA colors (i.e., partially transparent),
2. Ability to load bitmap images,
3. Ability to read current color of pixel in a given coordinate.

Ideally using JavaScript or Python.

Seems like HTML 5 Canvas can handle #2 and #3 but not #1, whereas SVG can handle #1 and #2 but not #3. Am I missing something (about either of these two)? Or are there other alternatives?

Comment: tur1ng, can you please provide an example? I failed to find any.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors

Answer (score 3):

PyGame can do all of those things. OTOH, I don't think it embeds into a GUI too well.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up going with Canvas. The "secret" of polygons is using paths. Thanks, "tur1ng"!

Answer (score 1):

GameJs does that and more - it's similar to the mentioned PyGame.

http://gamejs.org

Ability to draw polygons (not just rectangles!) with RGBA colors (i.e., partially transparent),

```
gamejs.draw.polygon (surface, color, pointlist, width)
```

Transparent colors can be defined as 'rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.1)' (last is alpha)

http://docs.gamejs.org/gamejs/draw/#polygon

Ability to load bitmap images,

```
var surface = gamejs.image.load('images/foo.png')
```

http://docs.gamejs.org/gamejs/image/

Ability to read current color of pixel in a given coordinate.

```
// a surface array is a special DOM canvas array
// that is superfast for per pixel access / manipulation

var srfArray = new SurfaceArray(display);
srfArray.set(50, 100, [255, 0, 0, 100]);
srfArray.get(20, 30);
```

http://docs.gamejs.org/gamejs/surfacearray/

Answer (score 0):

I voted for PyGame, but I would also like to point out that the new QT graphics library seems quite capable. I have not used PyQT with QT4 yet, but I really like PyQT development with QT3.

Answer (score -1):

maybe Raphael - http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html

Comment: How does it do #3?  It's a very thin wrapper on SVG and VML, so if Raphael can do it, then SVG could already do it.